# HTTP request in Meteor's package.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

At autopublish.meteor.com, we're trying to retrieve some external data about a package, namely its latest release tag [from GitHub](https://api.github.com/repos/summernote/summernote/releases/latest) or [the NPM registry](http://registry.npmjs.org/summernote/latest):

```
var version;
try {
  var packageJson = JSON.parse(Npm.require('fs').readFileSync('package.json'));
  version = packageJson.version;
} catch (e) {
  // package.json won't be found when running the example with the local copy
  // of the package because the current directory isn't the package dir
  // ... so fall back to other methods of getting the version
  version = HTTP.get('...').data.version;
}

Package.describe({
   name: 'foo',
   summary: 'bar',
   version: version,
});
```

The problem is that the HTTP package isn't available in `package.js`.

I've tried using [the request module](https://github.com/request/request), via `Npm.require('request')`, but that module is async and...

```
request.get('http://registry.npmjs.org/summernote/latest', function (err, res, body) {
  ...
  Package.describe({
    ...
  });
});
```

... fails because `Package.describe` needs to be run in a Fiber:

> Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.

The problem with that is that the Meteor singleton isn't available in `package.js` either.

**Is there a way to do this?**

---

Other things I've tried:

- using the NPM api, e.g. `npm.view('summernote');` - doesn't work because you can't `Npm.require('npm')`:

  > In package.js, Npm.require can only find built-in modules.
- using execFileSync to call the `npm` binary, but that doesn't work because execFileSync is only available in [Node v0.12.0, which Meteor doesn't use yet](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2310#issuecomment-76945384).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running in a fiber means using [node-fibers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fibers) so you can add it just like request with `Npm.require('fibers/future')`.

So this code gets a version of '0.6.1' for that module:

```
var request = Npm.require('request');
var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

var fut = new Future();

request.get('http://registry.npmjs.org/summernote/latest', function (err, res, body) {
  if (! err){
    fut.return (body);
  }
});
var body = JSON.parse(fut.wait());

Package.describe({
   name: 'foo',
   summary: 'bar',
   version: body.version
});
```